# Setup Cron Job on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-14.04

i have a couple dedicated servers and i need to run iptables -F twice a day
also clean partition dev/md1 once a day.

I m doing all this manually every day.

How i can setup a cron job to do this?

iptables -F and the other command i run
cp /dev/null /home/codes/a_codes/php/var/log/php-fpm.log

```
root@brusa-9:~# crontab -e
no crontab for root - using an empty one

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
1. /bin/ed
2. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
3. /usr/bin/vim.basic
4. /usr/bin/vim.tiny

Choose 1-4 [2]:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new file (name it as you want, it is free to you) in `/etc/cron.d`. This file must contain lines like:

```
0 */12 * * * <command to execute twice a day>
```

There are five buckets at the beginning of each line. These mean:

```
<Minute> <Hour> <Day_of_the_Month> <Month_of_the_Year> <Day_of_the_Week>
```

So, in the example above, you run that task at minute 0 and every 12 hours (so twice a day). If you want to make it to execute once a day, at 13:20 for example, it would be:

```
20 13 * * *  <task to run every day at 13:20>
```

Hope this help!